# How do you open a file in C++ from HTTP where the URL is NOT the file location

Tags: c++, http

I'm a first year comp sci student with a moderate knowledge of C++ and for a job I'm trying to put together a utility using a new U.S. Census Bureau API. It takes ID codes for things like state/county/census tract and the desired table and spits back out the desired table for the desired location.

[Here's an example of a query for population stats for California and New York.](http://thedataweb.rm.census.gov/data/2010/acs5?key=2fee2a7db5a7ddc4a7321ff7e3002176e1ce86c3&get=B02001_001E,NAME&for=state:06,36)

More examples can be found here: http://www.census.gov/developers/

My snag is that I've both never worked with files from HTTP and also I'm not sure how to handle a URL that outputs plain text but doesn't actually lead to the file location. Would it be possible to just use stdin? I don't understand how to handle the output given by one of the census query URLs.

Right now I'm using infile which I *know* isn't correct but I'm not sure a correct solution is either.

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at the Go language. It has a http package that would make this task very easy. See here - http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the data you're receiving is (apparently) generated on the fly rather than coming from a file doesn't really make any difference to you -- you get the same stream of bytes either way.

My immediate advice would be to use [`cURL`](http://curl.haxx.se/) for the job. Most of your work is generating a correct URL, which is what cURL specializes in. It'll then make it pretty easy to grab the data. From there, you can use any of quite a few JSON parser libraries (e.g., [yajl](http://lloyd.github.com/yajl/)), or you can parse it on your own (JSON is simple enough to make that fairly practical). A quick Google indicates that a fair number of people have already done this, and have various blog posts and such giving information about how to do it (though I suspect most of that is probably unnecessary).

Comment: I've written something rough for putting together the URLs and for parsing the array (I don't know if they work properly yet so I'll look at the libraries you suggested.) What I'm confused about is how to actually get the input. When you say it's the same stream of bytes either way, can I just use std input from a URL?

Comment: Also, I'm not having much success finding developers doing similar stuff on google, other than a USA Today API which looks moderately redundant. What search terms did you use? Thanks.

Comment: @ProtonBetaDecay: I searched for `curl json`, if memory serves.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I see. I misunderstood and thought you meant there were already a lot of U.S. Census API utilities out there which was puzzling because I hadn't seen any.

Comment: @ProtonBetaDecay: Oh, sorry 'bout that, but no, I just meant the same *general* idea, not consuming data from that specific site.

Comment: I'm using libcurl but having trouble understanding how to implement it in this context. The example source code for pulling a web page is [link]http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html[/link]. However let's say I wanted to return the contents of the page, as I would in the case of the json array, how do I return the contents of the URL? The "res" variable only seems to hold status codes. Thanks.

Comment: @ProtonBetaDecay: You normally use [curl_easy_setopt](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) with CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION and CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, to setup a function that'll be called, and the address of a buffer where it'll write the data as it comes in.